# How to fix this error?

Tags: lcd

Arduino: 1.8.8 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328P (Old Bootloader)"

```
libraries\TimerOne\TimerOne.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `TimerOne::isrDefaultUnused()':

(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_13'

libraries\Timer1Fast\Timer1Fast.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Multiple libraries were found for "Timer1Fast.h"
 Used: D:\apps\Arduino\libraries\Timer1Fast
 Not used: C:\Users\biril\Documents\Arduino\libraries\pwmTest
Multiple libraries were found for "TimerOne.h"
 Used: D:\apps\Arduino\libraries\TimerOne
 Not used: C:\Users\biril\Documents\Arduino\libraries\TimerOne-master
Multiple libraries were found for "LiquidCrystal_I2C.h"
 Used: C:\Users\biril\Documents\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal_I2C
 Not used: C:\Users\biril\Documents\Arduino\libraries\NewliquidCrystal
 Not used: C:\Users\biril\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino-LiquidCrystal-I2C-library-master
 Not used: D:\apps\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal
Multiple libraries were found for "Wire.h"
 Used: D:\apps\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\Wire
 Not used: D:\apps\Arduino\libraries\Wire
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Nano.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: What code causes this error? I think you have two libraries that both use the hardware "timer1".

Comment: Don't use both the TimerOne and Timer1Fast libraries together. Why you would want to, though, is anyone's guess...

Comment: thanks, i'll rearrange my libraries again.